# Playhavan more games widget

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, playhaven

I used these calls to show playHavan more game widget on button press.

```
-(void)showPlayHavanMoreGamePage
{
    PHPublisherContentRequest *request = [PHPublisherContentRequest requestForApp:PLAY_HAVAN_TOKEN secret:PLAY_HAVAN_SECRET placement:@"more_games_list" delegate:self];
    [request send];
}
```

It shows interstitial ads first then shows more games page. How can I avoid interstitial fullScreen ads on more game button tap and show only moregame widget ?

Image-1:

[image]

Image-2:

[image]

I wish to show only moregame widget shown in image 2 on 'More Games' button tap, how to avoid ads in image 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PlayHaven dashboard, edit your "More Games Button" and make sure the "Enable Featured Game Preroll" is uncheck. Can't insert image to my answer but heres the link for the screenshot. http://screencast.com/t/VDNsb7rY